# Loop from start to end to start in php

Tags: php, for-loop

how to print below format using only one for loop. Please tell is it possible to do this ?

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: Of course its possible. But you really should as least have a try at **doing your own homework**

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly I try but my browser is crashing.... I didnt getting any idea how to do i'm try from 2hrs

Comment: @ZakeerHussain Show us your attempts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds of ways to do it. This is just one:

```
for($i=-4; $i<5; $i++)
    print substr('12345', 0, 5-abs($i))."\n";
```